# Database for having very long but simple tables

Tags: database, mysql, postgresql, mariadb

I am in need for a database that can store very long tables.

E.g.

```
MYTAB
-----
name STRING
date DATETIME
mark INTEGER
value DOUBLE


"A.112.akizo", "2023-01-01 01:00", 0, 1234.54
"A.112.akizx", "2023-01-01 01:00", 0, -33.00
"A.113.boxrw", "2023-01-01 02:00", 0, 45.32
```

name and date would be my primary-key.

I need to store millions of rows per year. I will select by name/date and also update.
Do not need to have references to other tables. No need for SQL but addressing by name/date is mandatory.

My 1st approach would be a normal table in a DBMS (like MariaDB or PostgreSql) and maybe have it for each year if it gets too long (e.g. MYTAB_2022, MYTAB_2023).

Not sure if there are better ways for handling this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need relations or SQL, have you considered NoSQL? Such as [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/index.html) that definitely comes with scalability. And if you need a more local and free solution, since you didn't state, then e.g. [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) could work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [Timeseries Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database). Or a database for  logging data such as [RRDtool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) which is mature.

Third-party tools couldhelp visualize these datasets.

For nanosecond-resolution you could try [Prometheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_(software)) which is a monitoring system with a time series database.
Which product you choose depends on your requirements and preferences.

If you need fast loading times and your focus is on in-memory analytics, you could try [Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/) or [DuckDb](https://duckdb.org/) for instance